# Incorrect syntax trying to compile function

Tags: sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_WarrantyTrend
returns @myTable table
(
    Years int 
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @myTable
    SELECT distinct YEAR(CurDate) from EOD_Main ORDER BY YEAR(CurDate) ASC
    RETURN 
END
```

And I am getting these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_WarrantyTrend, Line 2
>   
> Incorrect syntax near 'returns'.
>   
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure fn_WarrantyTrend, Line 8
>   
> Must declare the table variable "@myTable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an error from syntax you made up, you should [consult the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_WarrantyTrend -- always use schema prefix
(
    @Years int -- need @variable syntax here
)
-- parameter list comes *before* RETURNS
RETURNS TABLE -- you should use an inline table-valued function when possible
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT CurDate = YEAR(CurDate) -- should alias the output column
      FROM dbo.EOD_Main -- again, always use SCHEMA prefix
      --ORDER BY YEAR(CurDate) ASC -- not possible to ORDER BY here without TOP
          -- the outer query that calls the function should apply any ORDER BY
  );
```

It's interesting, though, that you take this `@Years` parameter, and never use it...

You should also consider creating the function `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. And [here is background on always using the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).